# Collation Conflict for non-join T-SQL Code

Tags: t-sql

I have the following code and am receiving the following error:

```
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 37
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS" in the equal to operation.
```

What should I do to resolve this? Everything I found online has to do with joined tables.

```
   IF OBJECT_ID('SeanVault.dbo.TempVarIDs', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE SeanVault.dbo.TempVarIDs;
    Select VariableID, VariableName
    INTO SeanVault.dbo.TempVarIDs
    from Variable
            Where VariableName in (select VariableName from SeanVault.dbo.TempVarNames)
```

Comment: `Where VariableName in (select VariableName from SeanVault.dbo.TempVarNames) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Comment: @Lamak  Why is this a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @iamdave Because a code only answer is not a good answer...and I'm kinda tired, so I don't want to write what's needed to make it a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two columns VariableID and VariableNames have a different collation. You can bypass the collation configuration(if you don't control your data model for example), by providing an explicit collation :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SeanVault.dbo.TempVarIDs', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE SeanVault.dbo.TempVarIDs;
Select VariableID, VariableName
INTO SeanVault.dbo.TempVarIDs
from Variable
Where VariableName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS in (select VariableName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS from SeanVault.dbo.TempVarNames)
```

A long term solution would be to ALTER your columns' definition and adding the desired collation :

```
    ALTER TABLE Variable
      ALTER COLUMN VariableID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO

    ALTER TABLE TempVarNames
      ALTER COLUMN TempVarNames COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you it worked. These are tables used temporarily and dropped after the procedure is run so I don't think I'll go the ALTER route.